# Why is angle of attack information not displayed in the cockpit?

Tags: angle-of-attack, display

Would not it be useful to have the angle of attack information displayed on the flight display? I know that we have shakers that alert pilot when the critical AOA is exceeded, but still we have cases of pilots stalling the aircraft (sometimes stalling one wing more than other).
I am sure designers have considered this but not chose to display AOA. I am curious what the reason could be.

Comment: of which aircraft/flight display are we talking about?

Comment: AoA detectors are relatively expensive in GA aircrafts. Many jet airliners have them.

Comment: It has been a [recommendation from the BEA after AF447 disaster](https://www.bea.aero/docspa/2009/f-cp090601.en/pdf/f-cp090601.en.pdf) (p 205) to display the AoA: "*It is essential in order to ensure flight safety to reduce the angle of attack when a stall is imminent. Only a direct readout of the angle  of  attack  could  enable  crews  to  rapidly identify  the  aerodynamic  situation  of the aeroplane and take the actions that may be required.*"

Answer (score 17):

Many aircraft do include them, because it's very useful.

For example a modern 737:

[image: 737 AoA indicator]

A Garmin G1000 (one of the more common General Aviation glass cockpits):

[image: Garmin G1000 AoA indication]

Specifically the part that looks a bit like this

[image: Physical Garmin AoA indicator]

And a more traditional analog/mechanical gauge:

[image: Analog AoA indicator]

The problem is that usually when someone stalls, it's because they've made a mistake - not because they can't see the AoA. Either they're disorientated, or they've made a mistake with airspeed or an obstacle and are exceeding the aircraft's performance envelope.

Typically, the lack of an AoA dial isn't the reason you stall.

Comment: How would this display indicates if a single wing is stalled?

Comment: It generally doesn't, it relates to the position of the pitot tube I believe

Comment: I would take a further guess that when an accident happens due to a stall, it's because either the sensors have malfunctioned or the pilot doesn't believe the indicators.

Comment: Would you please make the AoA indicators more clear on the glass indicators? For the 737, I believe it's the 270° circle and `5.0` reading, but I'm not sure. For the Garmin, I believe I (not a pilot) can identify _most_ of the indicators, but none jump out and scream **AoA** to me. Hand drawn red circles would be most useful... ;) Thanks!

Comment: For the 737 it is indeed the 270 degree circle and 5.0 reading. For the Garmin it's that traffic-light-coloured set of lines to the right of the speed tape: the equivalent of this http://garmin.blogs.com/.a/6a00d83451bb7069e201b8d0737e3e970c-800wi - the segments light up relating to your AoA and equate to the green/yellow/read areas on the mechanical indicator

Comment: Ah, thank you! I thought those lines on the Garmin were glide slope indicators of some sort

Comment: Nope the glide slope on a Garmin appears just to the left of the altitude tape and looks much like the one you'd get on a 737 or A320 PFD

Comment: @FreeMan This may be a matter of the point of view, but I think it's better to think of an accident that happens due to a stall being because the pilot has improperly flown the airplane, not because of sensor failure. The sensors are there to warn the pilot that he's messing up, but they are not the cause.

Comment: This came up a lot regarding the crash of Air France 447. "If only the pilots had an AoA indicator, they would have had known they were in a nose-up stall and corrected." However, since the pitot tubes were jammed, causing faulty air speed readings, its likely the AoA indicator would likely have been incorrect as well.

Comment: @AFischbein The AOA sensors on AF447 worked properly throughout. They are vane-style sensors not dependent on the pitot tubes. They did fail, however, on [XL flight 888t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XL_Airways_Germany_Flight_888T?wprov=sfla1)

Answer (score 13):

Slightly off-topic, but I recently came across the "side string" which gives a direct reading of AoA.  Every gilder pilot is familiar with the [yaw string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaw_string), but in two years of learning to fly gliders, I'd never heard anyone mention the side string.
[image: Side String]

Now, in the ultralight / open-cockpit world they use a single piece of yarn mounted on a stick, which acts as a combination yaw and side string.

[image]

Comment: In every single type of glider I have flown, the change in noise and attitude were so clear near the stall, that I would have never paid attention to a side string like that.

Answer (score 7):

It strongly depends on the aircraft we're talking about.
As an example, this is the Head Up Display of an F/A-18 "Hornet":

[image: F/A-18 Head Up Display]

The number near the α is the angle of attack (AoA or α) measured in degrees.

I presume that only in certain conditions knowing the exact value of the AoA may turn out to be useful (when nearing the limits maybe...). Usually, exceeding the maximum AoA is a the result of a mistake, not the mistake itself.

Fly-By-Wire systems usually do not allow the pilots to exceed the max AoA (Airbuses' Alpha Floor for instance) during normal operations.

Comment: 20 degrees! Ouch, this guy must be pulling some serious G's.

Comment: Oh, it says 1.7G?

Comment: Do I remember correctly that the "W" symbol indicates where the nose is pointed and the circle with the three lines coming out of it, left right and upwards (at the bottom of the image just to the right of center) indicated the computed actual path of the airplane? If so that's yet another way to get a rough idea of the AoA from this kind of HUD.

Comment: @romkyns: Note the speed: At Mach 0.36 the F-18 will pull 1.7g but not 7.6; this needs far more speed.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, you're right, the "W-like" symbol indicates were the nose is pointed, the cross just over it is the "gun cross" that indicates the initial trajectory of the bullets fired from the gun while the "airplane" symbol represent the direction of the velocity vector of the airplane.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, romkyns, IIRC the number 7.6 should be the maximum pulled 'g' during the flight.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted many aircraft do have AOA indicators. Military A/C tend to have them next to the HUD on the left side.

The advantage using AOA over stall speed is that the stall AOA is constant while the stall speed depends upon weight. Greater weights => lower stall speeds.

This difference will be important when there are large differences in A/C weights. If your F-18 has 4x2000lb bombs the stall speed is much different depending upon whether those bombs are dropped or not.

With your average cessna, the weight change of the A/C/ does not change the stall speed significantly. An AOA indicator does not provide as much value relative to its cost and weight.

Comment: And with your average Cessna (or Piper &c) you tend to fly  a lot more by "seat of the pants" than by instruments (or at least I do).

Comment: An F-18's stall angle is the same whether or not it's carrying those bombs.  What changes is how fast it has to fly in order to stay in the air without exceeding that angle.

Comment: You are correct. A typo on my part. As the other paragraphs indicated, it is th stall speed that changes and not the AOA. Thanks for pointing it out.